# Expresso Store - Invalid Payment Method for Manual

Tags: expresso-store, checkout

Just installed Expresso and getting my feet wet with it. I'm using the default demo store it comes with to walk myself through the entire process and to figure out how to best utilize the software for my client's specific needs.

In particular, the client wants all items on the store to be free and with free shipping unless they want next day delivery (I already have a pretty good grasp on how to handle this). So, this means that I don't want to specify a payment method and use some preconfigured gateway for it- I don't need it.

I read that the best way to handle this is to simply use the "manual" payment method, but all I'm getting are constant errors.

Only code I added to the Checkout3 default template the Store provides you:

```
<select name="payment_method">
                <option value="paypal_express" selected>Paypal</option>
                <option value="manual">Manual</option>
            </select>

            {if error:payment_method}
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="alert alert-error">{error:payment_method}</div>
                    </div>
                {/if}
```

Earlier, I tried specifying the manual payment type without the above code in the checkout tag- same error being flagged.

Other than this, all I've done is comment out the  tag that houses the default payment code for the demo, given how I didn't need it.. Or thought I didn't.

Comment: Is the Manual gateway enabled in the payment methods list in Store Settings?

Comment: I totally missed that. I had enabled 'paypal' instead or something apparently? Because it was turned on but manual wasn't. 

Must've been when I was messing with that. Kudos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer posted:

The Manual gateway must be enabled in the Store payment methods settings for the Manual gateway to work.

Comment: Irony is I figured this out about 2 hours after posting this, and I just had to sit here and wait until someone (or I) could post someone and accept it as an answer. 

Congrats for being awesome though!

Comment: Glad you figured it out too!

Comment: Same deal with all payment methods even `payment_method="Dummy"`